# Нормализация БД (разделение данных)

Tags: sql, оптимизация

Есть две таблица:

[image: общая таблица]

имеет ли смысл разбивать ее на две:

[image: две]

Что бы получить прирост скорости выполнения запроса при обращении к ее отдельным полям (name или data).

Comment: А за счет чего вы собираетесь получить прирост скорости при таком разделении ? Да, в блок данных конечно влезет больше записей и полное сканирование таблицы для получения одного поля будет быстрее. А полного перебора в любом случае стоит избегать. Выборка одного поля из одной записи по id будет одинаково. А вот получение одновременно двух полей (очень частая задача) или создание новой записи - в разы медленнее

Comment: @Mike , и я так считаю , просто ведущий программист мне доказывает обратное , что даже если мы работаем с одним полем будет полный перебор по всем полям. (2) Если при записи во второе поле `data` попадает `NULL` (значение по умолчанию) скорость же останется как при записи одного поля. Просто проверяю что я не дурак )

Comment: А у ведущего программиста фамилия случаем не Сусанин ? Куда то не туда он ведет :)

Comment: Переборы конечно присутствуют при не фиксированной длине записи, но они в ОЗУ и это просто считается декодированием записи. Может потеряете пару миллисекунд на миллионе записей из за перепрыгивания поля что бы до другого добраться. Но самая дорогая операция в БД - обращение к диску. И в блоке данных лежат рядом несколько записей и в каждой записи все ее поля. А минимально с диска читается всегда блок и все поля после этого уже на руках

Comment: @Mike ну если посмотреть объективно то мы так же теряем время на условии по которому соединяем две таблицы в одну при полной выборке. так что выигрыша я никакого не вижу. а насчет сусанина, так никуда от него не деться, сделаю как он хочет, а правильную схему для себя в голове держать буду )

Comment: Если при этом есть соединение этих двух таблиц в одном запросе (что в общем то логично и очевидно) - то это вообще катастрофа. Он сначала возьмет запись из одной таблицы потом найдет по индексу ей пару во второй, как минимум в 2 раза больше дисковых операций. Сделать оба варианта с нормальным объемом данных, посмотреть разницу во времени и показать Сусанину, пусть голову ломает

Comment: @Mike непокорный джун то же катастрофа )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Приоритетной целью нормализации - является устранение избыточности данных. Конечно же не в ущерб падению производительности. В данном примере, скорее всего, скорость не возрастет. Т.к. **суммарное** количество индексов по полям останется прежним.

В любом случае - желательно составить пару-тройку "несентетических" запросов и проанализировать их план исполнения. Это будет вернее.